# How should I link two items with MouseMovementListeners?

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouseevent, mousemove

I'm working on a program that will display two "views" of the same set of items. So I need to have something set up so that when the top down view is changed, the side view is updated (and vice versa).

Here's a brief outline of the relevant code so you can get an idea of my structure so far:

```
public class DraggableComponent extends JComponent
{
    //Contains code for MouseMovementListener that makes the item draggable
}

public class ItemGraphic extends DraggableComponent
{
    //Code to render the graphic
}

public class Item
{
    private ItemGraphic topGraphic;
    private ItemGraphic sideGraphic;
}
```

I'm able to get each graphic to display fine in my GUI. I can also independently drag each graphic. I'm missing the "linking."
Some ideas I've been thinking about:

- Have one listener for the whole GUI. Loop through each Item and if
  the cursor is within the bounds of either graphic, move the other
  graphic. I'm concerned about the efficiency of this method.
- Multiple "paired" listeners (not quite sure how this would
  work, but the idea is that each graphic would have a listener for the other paired graphic)

Answer (score 2):

You need to have one "model" that is shared by both "views", with listeners on the models that update the views. This way if you change a view, a control will then change the model which will update both views. This is nothing more than yet another iteration of MVC (model-view-control) program design.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that you need some kind of intermediate model that the two components can share and monitor.

The idea is when you update/change on view, it updates the model with the required values.  All other interested parties are notified via a listener interface to the change and update them-selves accordingly.

We use a similar technique to link two scroll panes